# Summing Transformed Variables

Tags: data-transformation, skewness

I am using regression, and trying to create a construct. I have two continuous variables but they are each skewed/not normally distributed. I have $\log_{10}$ transformed each of them separately. Is it appropriate now to add them together to arrive at the measure for my construct?

If I cannot add them together, can I transform using square root and then add those together?

Is it ever appropriate to transform them using $\log$ or square root and then create a z score and add the z score together?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by a "construct" and what it is intended to be used for?  Please also edit your question to distinguish between independent and dependent variables.

Comment: Note that $\log_{10}(X)+\log_{10}(Y)=\log_{10}(XY)$ and $a\log_{10}(X)+b\log_{10}(Y)=\log_{10}(X^a Y^b)$.  Does this look meaningful in your exercise?

Comment: What is your construct? Why should its components be normally distributed? Should the construct be normally distributed?

Suppose the construct is "Familial wealth" - here I'd say that it would be better to add the raw data (how much is each member of family worth) and then, perhaps, transform the result.

With measures of national wealth - we look at median family income, not average of transformed incomes.

Comment: A construct is a concept like happiness which requires latent variable to measure. In this case I have two constructs, one is intended to measure firm visibility (#shares outstanding and # shareholders) and the second construct is market power measured as advertising intensity and R&D intensity - typically a firm has one or the other)Both constructs are IVs used to predict a DV

Comment: Henry - yes I understand the equation, in numeric terms, the log10 of 710 for example is 2.851258 and the log10 of 133 is 2.123852, so the summation = 4.97511. This of course is also the product of the two transformations. My fundamental question was is this acceptable to create a 2 variable construct - which I believe is, but can find no literature or text book explicitly stating it.  To beat a dead horse, is the same tru for adding 2 square roots?

Comment: You forgot to explain why you need the construct to be normally distributed!    In most cases there would be no such need.  You are probably better off with a construct that is interpretable!